# Многократный вызов функции в python

Tags: python, функции, python-3.x

```
points = [0.32,0.73,0.97,1.13,1.52,1.57,2.02,2.52,2.96,3.40,3.79]
data =[1.377,2.075,2.637,3.095,4.572,4.806,7.538,12.428,19.297,29.964,44.256]
x1 = [1.96,2.14,3.12,3.14,3.15,4.12,5.12,6.14,7.32,7.50,7.80]
x=1.96
def method(x,points,data):
    if len(data) == 1:
        return data[0]
    else:
        A = method(x,points[1:],data[1:])*(x - points[0])/(points[-1] - points[0])
        B = method(x,points[:-1],data[:-1])*(x - points[-1])/(points[0] - points[-1])
        #print (A+B)
        return A+B

print(method(x,points,data))
```

Функция правильно работает на одиночных точках (точка x), но хотелось бы, чтобы можно было задать список точек (список x1), для дальнейшего строительство графика по вычисленным точкам. Т.е нужно, чтобы он поочерёдно вносил числа со списка `x1` в method и там производились вычисления.

Все попытки не увенчались успехом.

Comment: А в чем конкретно проблема?

Comment: Ну мне надо, что бы было примерно так.
    for s in x1:
      s=method(x1,points,data)
как это сделать я не соображу.

Comment: Вот так и сделать.

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'float'

Comment: Вы предлагаете угадать что именно вы сделали и где именно получили такую ошибку?

Comment: `for s in x1: s=method(x1,points,data)` - вы путаете, `s` надо вместо `x1` писать в функции, т.е. как-то так: `for s in x1: current_result = method(s, points, data)`

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы получить список значений функции для заданного списка параметров:

```
y1 = [method(x, point, data) for x in x1]
```